# numpy random.choise - get several values with a minimum distance between them

Tags: python, numpy, random, combinations, probability

I am using numpy's [random.choise](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to get n integers in range(0,1000), where the same integer can't be chosen twice (replace=false).

But since each integer is a starting point of a sublist with a certain length (e.g.- 10), I want to have the random function not choosing any other integer that is +- 10 from already chosen ones.

using the p= parameter is not possible because i do not know in advance which n's will be chosen. (It could be possible to use a loop - where each iteration the +-10 integers from the newly chosen one are added to the list of probabilities with assigned probability 0, but that seems to me like a not optimal solution...)

for example:

```
myseries = list(range(1000))
n = 30 
blockRange = 10
np.random.choice(myseries, n, replace=False)
```

This returns 30 numbers, two of them are 33 and 37 - but I want to 'forbid' this (if 33 is there, no number between 24 to 42 should be allowed!)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to build it iteratively, it will be slower than a numpy method for sure but I can't find a way to do your particular random distribution with numpy.

I create a `res` list and a `forbidden` set.

I iterate `n` times (here `n=30`), try to compute a random number in specific bounds. If it's not *forbidden*, meaning that this number is not in the `forbidden` set I can add it to my `res` list.

And I also add to my `forbidden` set every `int` in this range : `[rand_num-9; rand_numb[`.

But if it is in my `forbidden` set I retry thanks to a `while` loop to find a suitable random number.

code :

```
import random 

n, lower_bound, upper_bound = 30, 0, 1000
res = []
forbidden = set()
for _ in range(n):
    rand_numb = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
    while rand_numb in forbidden:
        rand_numb = random.randint(0,1000)
    res.append(rand_numb)
    forbidden = forbidden.union(set(range(rand_numb-9, rand_numb+10)))
```

Comment: thanks, its working well. Because it is a long array (i.e. higher 'upper_bound' value than 1000 in my real case), it takes EXTREMELY SLOW to run (each time check if the rand_numb is already in the forbidden numbers... So I thought to change this logic and to do list.remove to each of the forbidden values, so that in the next iteration the array will be shorter. unfortunately, running list.remove(i) iteratively for many values is also very slow (but maybe I'm jsut doing it not optimally...). Just in case its relevant to others - you can consider changing this.

Comment: Actually check if a rand_numb is in forbidden is not slow at all, that's why I used a set (HashMap) because checking if a value is contained in a set() is very fast (you're not looping through every value until you find it). You could do something faster I think but it would be very hard to explain and code ... let me think about it

Answer (score 1):

A trick could be to generate random space between numbers and normalize it to stay in the given range. Then take the cumsum of the distance to obtain indices

Here is the code I use :

```
def space_random_opt(n, lower_bound, upper_bound, space):
    range_n = upper_bound-lower_bound 
    assert range_n >=space*n, "sample too tiny"    #check if sample is large enough
    coeffs = np.random.rand(n) #generate coefficients of spacing
    spacer = (range_n-n*space)/np.sum(coeffs) #normalize coeffs
    spacerz = (spacer*coeffs)+space #get distances
    idx = np.cumsum(spacerz).astype(int) #get indices
    return idx
```